# How to store an array in a User model in a Ruby-On-Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to save an array of strings in a column of my table `users`. I have this line in my migration file `add_column :users, :choices, :string`. This doesn't work as I am trying to store an array and not just a string, my terminal shows `Unpermitted parameter: :choices`. How can I store an array ?? (Obviously `add_column :users, :choices, :array` doesn't work.)

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to add in a table for `choices` and include a foreign_key/join to the `users` table? this would act like an array, but work with all databases

Comment: You can store an array of text at least in Postgres. What's your database version and Rails version? Are you able to use json if creating a new table doesn't suit you?

Comment: Using (PostgreSQL) 9.6.24 and Rails 6.0.4. Basically I am receiving this array from a multiple choice question in a form and it's linked to a User.

Answer (score 2):

The database column really has nothing to do with the error. You define array columns by defining a type and using the `array: true` option as arrays are typed in most databases unlike in Ruby:

```
add_column :users, :choices, :string, array: true
```

However this is usually a **bad idea** as you're violating first normal form (1NF) by putting multiple values in one column and giving up all the advantages that having a discrete table has in terms of normalization, assocations, foreign keys etc. This is idea that everyone entertains when they discover array columns - but is not really a good design decision.

`Unpermitted parameter: :choices` is raised when you pass an ActionController::Parameters instance with an unpermitted key. It has absolutely nothing to do with the underlying database column or the attribute.

You can whitelist array columns by passing a hash key with an empty array:

```
params.require(:user)
      .permit(:foo, :bar, choices: [])
```

This permits an array containing any type of permitted scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as this in your migration

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :choices, :string, array: true
  end
```

Then you probaly want to prevent writing non-array types.

```
#app/models/users.rb

  def choices=(input)
    raise TypeError, 'choices must be an array' unless input.is_a?(Array)
    super
  end
```